# Extents of British National Grid

Tags: coordinate-system, united-kingdom, bng

What are the valid extents of the British National Grid?

Are all tiles AA through ZZ valid, or is it just those which start with H,J,N,O,S,T that should be used?

Comment: Take a look here for more info: http://epsg.io/27700. I would understand it that only the letters you've mentioned are valid. Never seen grid refs outside of those. See this for a visual representation: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/British_National_Grid.svg/1200px-British_National_Grid.svg.png

Comment: I usually use 0,700000 and 0,1300000

Comment: They can be valid had RO references (Ireland in the past from a client) here are all of them together most are not used as not land but sea. https://britishnationalgrid.uk/